# a prime numbers that is a value of a simultaneous system of diagonal binary quadratic forms

Tags: number-theory

I encountered the following question as an exercise. Find a prime number $p$ that is *simultaneously* a value of the binary quadratic forms $x^2 + {n}y^2$ for all $n:1\leq{n}\leq{10}.$  I was trying to use the known theorems about such forms :

1. $p=x^2 + y^2$ if and only if $p\equiv {1({\rm mod}\ 4)}.$
2. $p=x^2 + 2y^2$ if and only if $p\equiv {1({\rm mod}\ 8)}.$
3. $p=x^2 + 3y^2$ if and only if $p\equiv {1({\rm mod}\ 3)}.$
4. $p=x^2 + 5y^2$ if and only if $p\equiv {1,9({\rm mod}\ 20)}.$

Would something like the Chinese Remainder Theorem help? I suppose I could just do a brute search, but am looking for a way to make a more "educated" search.
Also am woefully computer illiterate! So my attempts would be beyond crude in attempting a brute search for such a prime.

Comment: Set them equal to each other ? You might get ratios between inputs etc.

Comment: Well the case $n = 8$ seems to subsume the case $n = 2$, and the case $n=9$ subsumes $n=1$! But so far even if I consider multiples of $4,$ I cross $10$ in one step! This may cut down on the number of identities I set equal to each other. But your suggestion is noted. Will try! Thanks.

Comment: Well $$x^2+y^2=z^2+2a^2\implies x^2-z^2=2a^2-y^2$$ for example. We can factor 1 side.

Comment: Yes CRT helps it tells you it would need to be $1,49 \mod 120$ for those 4

Comment: Roddy-using your comment, I found a prime that satisfies many but not all (sadly) of the system

Comment: Roddy-using your comment, I found a prime that satisfies many but not all (sadly) of the system. $$241 = 4^2 + 15^2 = 7^2 + 3(8^2)  = 15^2+4(2^2) = 14^2 + 5(3^2) = 5^2 +6(6^2) = 13^2+8(3^2) = 4^2 + 9(5^2) = 9^2 + 10(4^2)$$ I got $n = 1,3,4,5,6,8,9,10.$ Am mssing $n =2$ and $n=7$. CLose but no cigar! I should look harder...

Comment: $241=13^2+2(6^2)$ following your advice for  replacing 8 and 2...  But it can only be 1,2,4 mod 7 to work for 7 ...